# Bound arc-length of certain continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$

Tags: riemann-integration

> A continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ has the properties
>
> (a)  $f(0)=f(1)=0$
>
> (b) $f'(x)$ is a non-increasing function of $x$.
>
> Prove that the arc-length of the graph does not exceed $3$.

As I understand from the question that we want to prove that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx <3$.

The first property give the conditions of Rolle's theorem implies that $f'(c)=0$, $c \in(0,1)$.

The second property gives the clue of the max value exists at $c$.

I tried to use first mean value theorem of integral, but no conclusion find.

Is there is any other technique to solve this question?

Comment: [Arc-length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) would be $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$

Comment: How I calculate the upper bound of of $f^{'}(x)$.

Comment: By Rolle's theorem, $\exists c\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. $f'(x)$ is non-increasing, so $f'(x)\le  f'(c)=0  \;\forall x \in (0,1), x\ge c; f'(0)\ge f'(x)\ge  f'(c)=0  \;\forall x \in (0,1), x\le c$.

$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx=\int_0^c \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx+\int_c^1 \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx\le \int_0^c \sqrt{1+(f'(0))^2}dx+\int_c^1 dx=c\sqrt{1+(f'(0))^2}+(1-c)$

Comment: I could not think of how to properly bound f'(0) yet, but once I (or anyone else) figured out that part we're done.